# Detect linear zones from 2d dataset

Tags: python, opencv, ransac

I have a large 2D-dataset (.csv) with values from a pressure sensor.
The first value is the pressure value, while the second one records the time the measure was taken.
Looking at the plot, I can see a cluster of points (due noise) where you can detect some linear parts (that is the "good working zone") and non-linear zones.
I thought to use a RANSAC algorithm to detect linear zones, but I'm not sure it's the best way.
By OpenCV I can isolate linear path and it seems working well, but my problem is transforming a 2D dataset in a "Mat": my sensor gives me 32bit values and tests takes days with a sub-second data rate so the final 2d-matrix is an enormous set of 0-1!
So, according to you, what is the best way to detect linear patterns in a 2d-dataset?

edit:
Sending a real dataset is quite problematic, because of its weight (approx 100Mb) and time need to achieve a test (days).
I can send a plot to show my problem.
[image: myplot]

As You can see, RANSAC works apparently well, but my fear is that a kind of dataset as this:
[image: myplot]
can cause erroneous results (the first linear part not detect).
An idea is to "split" my dataset in parts but it doesn't seem very efficient...
Is there a method to detect multiple linear zones by RANSAC?

P.S
Here an example code by Python for RANSAC

`import numpy as np
     import pandas as pd
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
     from skimage.measure import LineModelND, ransac
     // x,y are vectors: 
     // x -> time value
     // y -> pressure value @xtime
     data = np.column_stack([x, y])
     model = LineModelND()
     model.estimate(data)
     model_robust, inliers = ransac(data, LineModelND, min_samples=2, residual_threshold=0.01, max_trials=1000)
     outliers = inliers == False
     line_x = np.arange(x.min(), x.max()+1)
     fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     ax.plot(data[inliers, 0], data[inliers, 1], '.b', alpha=0.6,label='Linear Data')
     ax.plot(data[outliers, 0], data[outliers, 1], '.r', alpha=0.6,label='Non Linear Data')
     ax.legend(loc='lower right')
     plt.show()`

Comment: I think to incldue the plot will help get the question get better answers

Comment: Sending a real dataset is quite problematic, because of its weight (approx 100Mb) and time need to achieve a test (days). I can send a plot to show my problem....

Comment: I understand that you somehow really have assignment to use visual recognition for this. Otherwise, my advice is not to use pictures at all. Linearity is a mathematical feature, using raw data would give you much more precise results.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you!